# How to use gevent with Kombu

Tags: rabbitmq, gevent, kombu

I am writing a basic publish-subscribe script in python using kombu and rabbitmq along with gevent. How can we switch context to the publisher when the consumer is waiting on the queue until a message arrives? I tried using gevent.sleep() but its not working in my case

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue May 30 12:15:56 2017

@author: kartikkillawala
"""
from kombu import Connection,Exchange,Queue,Producer
from kombu.mixins import ConsumerMixin

import gevent
from gevent import Timeout

class Worker(ConsumerMixin):

    def __init__(self,connection,queues):
        self.connection=connection
        self.queues=queues


    def get_consumers(self,Consumer,channel):
        return([Consumer(queues=self.queues,callbacks= self.on_message] )])

    def on_message(self,body,message):
        print("Got Message: {0}".format(body))
        message.ack()
        self.should_stop=True
        gevent.sleep(1)


class MessageVerify:

    exchange_name = "Test-Exchange"
    exchange_type = "direct"
    queue_name = "Test-Queue"
    routing_key = "ABC"

    connection_producer = None

    channel_producer = None

    exchange_producer = None

    producer = None
    consumer = None

    queue = None
    worker = None

    def __init__(self,rabbitmq1):
        self.connection_producer = Connection(hostname=rabbitmq1['host'],userid=rabbitmq1['username'],password=rabbitmq1['password'])

        self.channel_producer = self.connection_producer.channel()

        self.exchange_producer = Exchange(name =self.exchange_name,type=self.exchange_type)

        self.queue = Queue(name=self.queue_name,exchange=self.exchange_producer,routing_key=self.routing_key)
        self.queue.maybe_bind(self.connection_producer)
        self.queue.declare()

    def sendMessage(self,routing_key,data):

        self.producer = Producer(channel=self.channel_producer,exchange=self.exchange_producer,routing_key=routing_key)
        self.producer.publish(data,routing_key=routing_key)
        print("[p]Published Message",data,'with routing key',routing_key)
        gevent.sleep(2)        


    def receiveMessage(self,routing_key,timeout=120):
        try:
            print ("Worker run")
            timer = Timeout(timeout)
            timer.start()
            gevent.sleep(2)
            self.worker = Worker(self.connection_producer,self.queue)
            self.worker.run()
        except Timeout:
            print("Connection Timeout")


rabbitmq1 = {
        "username":"guest",
        "password":"guest",
        "host":"localhost"}
msg_verify = MessageVerify(rabbitmq1)
threads = [gevent.spawn(msg_verify.receiveMessage("ABC",timeout=120)),gevent.spawn(msg_verify.sendMessage("ABC","Sample Message"))]
gevent.joinall(threads)

print ("After joinall")
```

Comment: In case anyone finds this in the future, when using spawn, you need to pass your function itself and its arguments to spawn, instead of invoking it with the arguments. That results in synchronous execution and a gevent error because the first spawn argument is not callable. Of course, in case of interdependecies, like in this code, synchronous execution just means it'll deadlock, so you'll never see the error.